# failed/success percentage from total items

Tags: c#

Let's assume I have 8 items.

From these 8, 5 are success and 3 failure.

If I want to get the success and failure in percentage with 2 decimals precission I will do like this:

```
int total = 8;
int success = 5;
int failure = 3;

string success =((decimal)((success * 100) / total)).FormatDecimal();

string failure = ((decimal)((failure * 100) / total)).FormatDecimal();
```

Format decimal is an extension that will convert decimal to string with x amount of decimals.

```
public static string FormatDecimal(this decimal value, int decimals = 2)
{
   return value.ToString(string.Format("0.{0}", new string('0', decimals)));
}
```

Now if I take my calculator and I do this, the result is correct:

```
success: (5 * 100) / 8 = 62.5 %

failure: (3 * 100) / 8 = 37.5 %
```

However my solution return me 62.00 % and 37.00%

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is running with [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) but you calculator can do floating-point division.

Your `(5 * 100) / 8` returns `62`, not `62.5` since both operand is `int` and this operation will always disregards fractional part.

From [`/` Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

> When you divide two integers, the result is **always** an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2.

If you change your `total` to `double`, you can fix this since you start doing floating-point division not integer division.

```
double total = 8.0;
```

Check out;

- [7.7.2 Division operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the division operator `/` for integers only return the integer part.

If need to cast to float, double or decimal.

```
var result = ((float)(5 * 100)) / 8;
```

If any of the values you are dividing is a float, double or decimal, the division operator will support the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic mistake at C#. You have defined the calculation wrong.

`(success * 100) / total`

It means that after `success * 100`, the result will be parsed as integer. It is now 300 in integer. 300 / 8 = 37 in integer.

Instead, you can replace the `100` with `100m` to force convert them to decimal.